# Filling with transparency using Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, transparency, argb

I created an ARGB BufferedImage. Now I'd like to reinitialize it with a transparent background. I tried the following code:

```
(...) 
if( this.offscreen==null  ||
    this.offscreen.getWidth()!= dim.width ||
    this.offscreen.getHeight()!= dim.height )
    {
    this.offscreen=new BufferedImage(
       dim.width,
       dim.height,
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
     }
Graphics2D g=this.offscreen.createGraphics();
g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,0));
g.clearRect(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
(...)
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea on how to do this please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Didn't work how?  Threw an exception? created a blue image? created a null image?

Comment: my screen is black on a white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g.clearRect(..)` fills the selected rectangle with the background colour of the `Graphics2D` object. You're better off doing `g.fillRect(..)` which would give the intended result with your code, or set the background colour of the `Graphics2D` object beforehand (`g.setBackground(..)`).

Also, you may have to do `g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));` before the fill so that it sets the buffer properly (ignore destination buffer data, only use source data -- in this case, the fill operation). Not sure what the default is for this value, but you should set it back to that afterwards to ensure proper operation.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem before and I solved it with a really narrow trick. 
Here is the deal:

In the constructor of the paint Class take a screen shot of the System but be careful

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 23, xScreen, yScreen));
```

And where you want to clear the screen

```
g2D.drawImage(image, null, /*your Image observer*/);
```